# logical array more than one dimension

Tags: matlab, matrix, nan

```
        adc.nv is 789 X 2 array

        in = ~isnan(adc.nv);

        nv = adc.nv(in);
```

after I do this I am getting 1576 X 1 array instead of 788 X 2 array

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour is explained here: http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/math/f1-85462.html#bq7egb6-1

Because

```
in = ~isnan(adc.nv);
```

`in` can have a different number of true/false element in each row and/or column, it is possible that the resulting matrix `adc.nv(in)` has a different number of elements per row/column and thus cannot be constructed as *a matrix* So Matlab throws it all together in one vector.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you meant to eliminate rows containing NaN values. Example:

```
>> x = rand(6,2);
>> x(3,1) = nan; x(5,2) = nan;
>> x
x =
      0.81472       0.2785
      0.90579      0.54688
          NaN      0.95751
      0.91338      0.96489
      0.63236          NaN
      0.09754      0.97059
```

Now:

```
>> newX = x(~any(isnan(x),2),:)
newX =
      0.81472       0.2785
      0.90579      0.54688
      0.91338      0.96489
      0.09754      0.97059
```

Comment: alternatively: `x(any(isnan(x), 2), :) = [];`